# Is using a colon before a table of values correct?

Tags: punctuation, colons

Is it correct to use a colon before a table? For example:

> The required configuration is provided in the table below:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless the style manual that you're using explicitly forbids it, there's no problem using a colon or an end-stop (period) after *below*. The meaning doesn't change and the choice is not based on the rules of English grammar, only the variable rules of English punctuation.

Comment: I'd prefer a colon here to match with the close relation (in both subject matter and layout) between the preceding and the following. Obviously, the choice would have to be a full stop with: 'The required configuration is shown in table 24 on page 342.'